# Routing problem with more than four stage

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, flutter-getx

I have developed a mobile app using [Getx](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) formal example ([example_nav2](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/tree/master/example_nav2)).
Routing is works for the following (three parts)
`/home/wallet/transact`
But for the following case (four parts) it does not works  (without throwing any errors)
`/home/wallet/transact/details`
(Of course, the content of Get.rootDelegate changes and everything seems working)

In the whole project, the problem occurs when the address reaches the fourth rout, but with three parts it works properly.
I used the following command to call the page

```
Get.rootDelegate.toNamed (Routes.DETAILS)
// Routes.DETAILS ="/home/wallet/transact/details"
```

Here is my routing code

```
static final routes = [
    GetPage (
      name: '/',
      page: () => RootView (),
      binding: RootBinding (),
      participatesInRootNavigator: true,
      preventDuplicates: true,
      children: [
        GetPage (
        name: _Paths.HOME,
        page: () => HomeView (),
        children: [
          GetPage (
            name: _Paths.WALLET,
            page: () => walletView (),
            children: [
              GetPage (
              name: _Paths.TRANSACT,
              page: () => TransactView (),
                children: [
                  GetPage (
                    name: _Paths.DETAILS,
                    page: () => DetailsView ()
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ],
  ),],
)]
```

**Flutter Version:**
2.5.0

**Getx Version:**
4.3.8

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to take a look to the navigator 2 new routing implementation available [here](https://github.com/Bdaya-Dev/getx/blob/nav2_doc/documentation/en_US/nav2.md), it may helps debug the issue